# Convert String to Date field for SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to convert a string to a date field. The field stores 30 characters. Dates, when present, are formatted as 'yyyymmdd' (20170202). In all cases, dates have 22 spaces after. I need to format this field as a date field like this: dd-mm-yyyy.

I've tried several formulas: 
`TO_CHAR(PERSACTION.NEW_VALUE_02, 'dd-mm-yyyy')` ,`TO_CHAR(PERSACTION.NEW_VALUE_02, 'yyyymmdd')`, `trim(TO_CHAR(PERSACTION.NEW_VALUE_02, 'yyyymmdd'))` with error message: invalid number format model. Your expertise is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Don't understand that you say the field is date but holds 30 characters. Please include the table definition.

Comment: You want to convert string **to date**. Exact quote from your title and from your post. Now, Oracle has functions `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE`. If you want to convert **to date**, which of these two functions (again, their names are `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE`) do you think is more likely to be the right one?

Comment: The table is a String(30). And I agree, I wish we had control over how the data is stored in the table but sadly we don't.

Comment: On a different note, if you want to convert **to date** then there is no "format" - date fields don't have formats. The formats are only for strings, when you convert a string to a date (as you store data in the table in the proper data type, which is DATE) and when you convert a date back to a string, ONLY FOR REPORITING PURPOSES.

Answer (score 3):

```
to_char(to_date( rtrim(new_value_02), 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Should do the trick. rtrim removes spaces on right side of string. Then I convert it to date using the date format specified, and then convert it to a string again in the desired format.

Comment: If the OP wants to convert to **date**, why is `TO_CHAR` needed at all?

Comment: This worked perfectly, I will keep this for future use too, thank you very much

Comment: @mathguy good point. I added this because he specifically mentions a date format as result. But a date in datatype Date has no format, it's just the representation of a specific date. Just leave the to_char out and you'll have a date.

Answer (score 2):

Did tried to convert to date format and then to char again?

`TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(PERSACTION.NEW_VALUE_02,'yyyymmdd'),'dd-mm-yyyy')`

Comment: If the OP wants to convert to **date**, why is `TO_CHAR` needed at all?

Comment: Because it needs to be char. The value is stored in a text field not in a date field as Tania asked.

Answer (score 1):

Please, please, **please** do not store DATEs and CHARACTER datatypes. This will only lead to issues that can be avoided when using the DATE datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the *string* 20170202 to another *string* and not actually a date (which would have no intrinsic formatted text representation), you could optionally use a regular expression to transform it, instead of converting to a date and back:

```
select regexp_replace('20170202     ', '^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}) +$', '\3-\2-\1')
from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE(
---------------
02-02-2017
```

Or you could use `substr` instead of `regexp_substr`, which may perform better even if you have to call it three times; using a CTE just to avoid repeating the value:

```
with t(str) as (
  select '20170202     ' from dual
)
select substr(str, 7, 2) ||'-'|| substr(str, 5, 2) ||'-'|| substr(str, 1, 4)
from t;

SUBSTR(STR
----------
02-02-2017
```

If you do convert to a date and back you would uncover any values which cannot be converted, as they will cause an exception to be thrown. That would imply you have bad data; which would have been avoided by using the right data type in the first place, of course. These will convert any old rubbish, with varying results depending on how far the strings stray from the pattern you expect - but including strings like '20170231' which represent an invalid date. And null value or strings of just spaces will be converted to odd things with the substr version, but you could filter those out.

You can see the kind of variation you would get with some sample data that doesn't match your expectations:

```
with t(str) as (
  select '20170202     ' from dual
  union all select '20170231     ' from dual
  union all select '2017020c     ' from dual
  union all select '2017020      ' from dual
  union all select '201702021    ' from dual
  union all select '             ' from dual
  union all select null from dual
)
select str,
  regexp_replace(str, '^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}) +$', '\3-\2-\1') as reg,
  substr(str, 7, 2) ||'-'|| substr(str, 5, 2) ||'-'|| substr(str, 1, 4) as sub
from t;

STR           REG           SUB          
------------- ------------- -------------
20170202      02-02-2017    02-02-2017   
20170231      31-02-2017    31-02-2017   
2017020c      2017020c      0c-02-2017   
2017020       2017020       0 -02-2017   
201702021     201702021     02-02-2017   
                              -  -       
                            --
```

With the anchors and whitespace expectation, the regular expression doesn't modify anything that doesn't consist entirely of 8 numeric characters. But it can still form invalid 'dates'.